# Unable to add media item to the queue using Media Controller

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer, android-mediasession

I am trying to create a Podcast player.  So following the [Android Universal Media Player](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer) source code. The problem I am facing is, I do not know my playlist ahead of time,  and the playlist creation is upon the user interaction. So I need to add/ remove Media Items from my Activity/ Fragment. My code is very alike the UMP sample app, also I have modified the MusicService's mediaSession

from

```
// Create a new MediaSession.
    mediaSession = MediaSessionCompat(this, "MusicService")
            .apply {
                setSessionActivity(sessionActivityPendingIntent)
                isActive = true
            }
```

to

```
// Create a new MediaSession.
    mediaSession = MediaSessionCompat(this, "MusicService")
            .apply {
                setSessionActivity(sessionActivityPendingIntent)
                isActive = true
                setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS
                        or MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_QUEUE_COMMANDS
                        or MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS)
            }
```

And I am  trying to Add an item to the queue like below

```
fun addRandomMedia() {
    if (mediaSessionConnection.isConnected.value == true) {
        val mediaDescription = MediaDescriptionCompat.Builder()
                .setMediaId("wake_up_01")
                .setTitle("Intro - The Way Of Waking Up (feat. Alan Watts)")
                .setMediaUri(Uri.parse("https://storage.googleapis.com/uamp/The_Kyoto_Connection_-_Wake_Up/01_-_Intro_-_The_Way_Of_Waking_Up_feat_Alan_Watts.mp3"))
                .build()
        mediaSessionConnection.mediaController.addQueueItem(mediaDescription)
    }
}
```

But I am always getting this below exception

```
Process: com.example.android.uamp.next, PID: 8446
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This session doesn't support queue management operations
    at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaControllerCompat$MediaControllerImplApi21.addQueueItem(MediaControllerCompat.java:1988)
    at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaControllerCompat.addQueueItem(MediaControllerCompat.java:316)
    at com.example.android.uamp.viewmodels.MainActivityViewModel.addItemToQueue(MainActivityViewModel.kt:118)
    at com.example.android.uamp.MainActivity$onCreate$3.onClick(MainActivity.kt:68)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Here is the addQueueItem code form support v4 media package

```
@Override
    public void addQueueItem(MediaDescriptionCompat description) {
        long flags = getFlags();
        if ((flags & MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_QUEUE_COMMANDS) == 0) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                    "This session doesn't support queue management operations");
        }
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putParcelable(COMMAND_ARGUMENT_MEDIA_DESCRIPTION, description);
        sendCommand(COMMAND_ADD_QUEUE_ITEM, params, null);
    }
```

So, I feel must be issues with getFlags method or I am missing something here, as the if check is always true.

To reproduce this issue, I have forked the sample and added the above code in the app. Here is the full code link
[Here is the code to reproduce](https://github.com/DhimanDasgupta/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/tree/master)

Comment: Did you find a way to solve it?

Comment: Hi @AlexandruCircus,  For my use case I used a Local Broadcast Receiver to add the items to the queue, where I am sending the list of Media Description objects.

I was able to use the above approach since, in my use case there was no Add to queue functionality, there I needed to replace the old queue with the new queue, so it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Are u using `MediaSessionConnector`?
The problem is the flags are overridden in constructor of `MediaSessionConnector`.
So u need to call `mediaSession.setFlags(flags)` after creating an instance of `MediaSessionConnector`.

```
mediaSessionConnector = MediaSessionConnector(mediaSession).also {
         
// ...

it.mediaSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS
                    or MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_QUEUE_COMMANDS
                    or MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS)
}
```